# How to insert circle on secon tab on tabfolder, how to access second tab

Tags: java, swt

how to draw a circle on second tab ? becouse i have, buttons on every tab, how i can sepperate them?

```
package shelllab;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final Display display = new Display();
         final Shell shell = new Shell (display);

            shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
            shell.setText("ShellExample");
            shell.setSize(700,500);

            final Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
            Menu bar = new Menu (shell, SWT.BAR);
            shell.setMenuBar (bar);
            MenuItem f1 = new MenuItem (bar, SWT.CASCADE);
            f1.setText ("&Файл");
            MenuItem f2 = new MenuItem (bar, SWT.CASCADE);
            f2.setText ("&О программе");
            Menu s1 = new Menu (shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
            f1.setMenu (s1);
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem (s1, SWT.PUSH);
            MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem (s1, SWT.PUSH);
            MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem (s1, SWT.PUSH);

            final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder (shell, SWT.BORDER);
            Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea ();
            tabFolder.setLocation (clientArea.x, clientArea.y);
            tabFolder.setSize(400, 500);
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                TabItem item1 = new TabItem (tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
            }

            f2.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
                public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                    MessageDialog.openWarning(shell, "Внимание", "Демонстрация работы с shell - лаба №2");

                }
            });     
            item.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
                public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                    //System.exit(0);
                    GC gc = new GC(tabFolder); 
                    Rectangle bounds = tabFolder.getBounds(); 
                    gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN)); 
                     gc.fillOval(50,50,200,200);

                }
            });     
            item2.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
                public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                    tabFolder.getItem(0).setText("This is example 1");
                    Button b1 = new Button(tabFolder, SWT.PUSH);
                    b1.setSize(180, 40);
                    b1.setText("Выбрать цвет для tabfolder2");
                    b1.setLocation(5, 25);
                    Button b12 = new Button(tabFolder, SWT.PUSH);
                    b12.setSize(180, 40);
                    b12.setText("Выбрать цвет для tabfolder3");
                    b12.setLocation(5, 80);



                    final Combo c = new Combo(tabFolder, SWT.READ_ONLY);
                      c.setBounds(250, 35, 100, 20);

                        String items[] = { "red", "blue", "green"};
                        c.setItems(items);

                        final Combo c2 = new Combo(tabFolder, SWT.READ_ONLY);
                          c2.setBounds(250, 90, 100, 20);

                            String items2[] = { "red", "blue", "green"};
                            c2.setItems(items2);
                    b1.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                          public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                          //tabFolder.setForeground(blue);
                              if (c.getText().equals("red"))
                              {


                                  //tabFolder.getItem(2).setControl(tabFolder);

                              }
                          }
                        });


                    //tabFolder.getItem(0).setData(b1);
                }

            }); 

            item.setText("Выход Ctrl+Q");
            item.setAccelerator (SWT.MOD1 + 'Q');
            item2.setText("Пример №1 Ctrl+1");
            item2.setAccelerator (SWT.MOD1 + '1');
            item3.setText("Пример №2 Ctrl+2");
            item3.setAccelerator (SWT.MOD1 + '2');


            tabFolder.getItem(0).setText("Example1");
            tabFolder.getItem(1).setText("Example2");
            tabFolder.getItem(2).setText("Example3");


            shell.open();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
              if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
              }
            }
            display.dispose();
    }

}
```

how to draw a circle on second tab ? because i have, buttons on every tab, how i can separate them?

is it any, SWT "form designer" for free downloading?

this is filling :

```
GC gc = new GC(tabFolder); 
Rectangle bounds = tabFolder.getBounds(); 
gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN)); 
gc.fillOval(50,50,200,200);
```

Comment: Syntax of grammars, it is hard parsing. why. Pls expain this.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't lot of SWT designers, but [WindowBuilder pro](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html) is a good choice (and it's free).

To second part of your question, check [SWT documentation for TabFolder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TabFolder.html), especially the methods

`TabItem[] getItems()` - returns an array of TabItems which are the items in the receiver
`TabItem[] getSelection()` - returns an array of TabItems that are currently selected in the receiver
`TabItem getItem(int index)` - returns the item at the given, zero-relative index in the receiver

By those you can obtain the `TabItem` you want (e.g. the second tab), and then use it for your `GC` instance creation. Your circle will then be only on selected tab..